# passing params through ajax to php

Tags: php, ajax

I know this is a very basic question, but i couldnt figure how to fix the code even after crawling the web for past 1 hour. 
I have an unordered list containing the information about the categories in the database, with cat_id as primary key. and a subject table with cat_id as its foreign key, so i want to access the subjects table through ajax request for given category ID. below is the code i used to generate categories. Where i am stuck is, i dont know which DOM element to fetch in order to send the unique id in the url parameter .. 
thanks ..

```
    <ul id="search_form">
       <?php
       $cat = Category::find_all();
       foreach($cat as $category) {
           echo '<li id="';
           echo $category->cat_id;
           echo '"><a href="subject.php?id=';
           echo $category->cat_id;
           echo'">';
           echo $category->category;
           echo '</a></li>';

       }

       ?>
    </ul>
    <div id="results">
        <!-- ajax contents goes here -->
    </div>
```

the ajax file is

```
    window.onload = init;
    function init() {
      if (ajax) {
        if (document.getElementById('results')) {
          document.getElementById('search_form').onclick = function() {

            ajax.open('get', 'subject.php?id='+id ); // subject.php?id=
            // how will i pass the variable
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
              handleResponse(ajax);
            }
            ajax.send(null);
            return false; 
          } 
        }
      } 
    } 
    function handleResponse(ajax) {
      if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
        if ((ajax.status == 200) || (ajax.status == 304) ) {
          var results = document.getElementById('results');
          results.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
          results.style.display = 'block';

        } 
      } 
    }
```

and the subject.php

```
    <?php 
    //include("tpl/header.php");
    include("includes/initialize.php");
    ?>
       <h2></h2>
        <?php
            if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
                $id= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
                $subject = Subject::find_subject_for_category($id);
                foreach($subject as $subj) {
                    echo $subj->subject_title;
                }
            } else {
                echo "No ID Provided";
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used Jquery to do these kind of things and it works fine for me.

```
$.ajax({
  type: GET,
  url: "subject.php",
  data: {id: $('#search_form :selected').val()},
  success: function(result){
    // callback function
  }
});
```

Comment: well, i am not familiar with jquery thing.. which function should i call on success ?

Comment: It is a callback function which is triggered only when your ajax call is successful. You can write your code or call other function that performs the task with the "result" returned by the ajax call if any. It could be left blank also.

Comment: $("#search_form").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                type: GET,
                url: "subject.php",
                data: {id: $('#search_form :selected').val()},
                success: function(result){
                    $("#result").html(result);
                // callback function
                }
                });
           }
// this doesnt work ..

Comment: assuming you are not familiar with jquery you need to include jquery library first, include this in your head <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and then try

Comment: i havent coded jquery before, but i have used a lot of plugins in my clients website. but thot its time to get ma hands dirty on learning it. well, this one is just a test script, and i m stuck in the middle.. when i hardcode the id variable i get the asynchronous response

Comment: just to make sure what error are you getting? is it returned to the success function or not?. Well FYI what ever you echo on php will be returned in the result. Also it has error property similar to success. Please try this and let me know

Comment: well, actually it dint return to the success function, whenever i click the link, instead of giving me asynchronous results, it opens the file as if we had no ajax call..

Comment: I just noticed you are missing ); at the end to close your click event. No idea if thats a typo or the issue